# Finite size energy levels

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, vacuum

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05499). In section 5 they consider a 2d QFT in finite size geometry (cylinder of radius $R$). They say that the energy levels of stationary states ($|n \rangle$) therein will behave as
$$E(R) = F_0 R + (\text{terms bounded at } R \rightarrow \infty)$$
where $F_0$ is the vacuum energy density. In particular, a bit later they consider a 2d CFT and they say the energy levels are
$$E(R) = F_0 R - \frac{C}{R}$$
where $C= C_n = \frac{\pi}{6} \Big( c - 12 (\Delta_n + \bar{\Delta}_n ) \Big)$, $c$ is the central charge and $\Delta$, $\bar{\Delta}$ are the eigenvalues of the operators $L_0$ and $\bar{L}_0$.

I understand the $- \frac{C}{R}$ in the CFT case, but I don't understand the $F_0 R$. Where does it come from? In particular, is it present in string theory? What is its interpretation?

**EDIT:** I just realized the same expression appears in Di Francesco, but with not much explanation:

> "If we suppose that there is a free energy $f_0$ per unit area in the $L \rightarrow \infty$ limit, then [...]
> $$F_L = f_0 L - \frac{\pi c}{6 L} \qquad \qquad \qquad (5.143)"$$

What is the meaning of that free energy density?